# Pandas groupby and judgement on dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where certain rows are classified as either 'pass' or 'fail'. I am trying to make an overall judgement on items depending on how many times they pass/fail.

pandas ver 23.4

Given the following df:

*note: several other columns exist but for this purpose, only these two columns matter

```
Name    Judgement
A        Pass
A        Fail
A        Fail
A        Pass
X        Pass
X        Pass
Z        Pass
Z        Pass
Z        Fail
F        Pass
```

To make the overall judgement, we look at the number of times each item passes/fails. An item **that occurs more than twice** can only be judged as 'Overall Pass' if (# of pass == # of fail). Items that occur once need no further judgement.

Ex output below:

```
Name    Judgement
A        Pass
X        Pass
Z        Fail
F        Pass
```

Notice `A` passes because it has 2 Pass and 2 Fail so 2/2 = 1 == **Pass**

`Z` fails because it has 2 Pass and 1 Fail so 2/1 = 2 == **Fail**

My thinking:

Do a groupby on `df['Name']` while also joining `Judgement` and simply counting the number of times each judgement type occurs for each Name. Is there a cleaner way to do this? This idea seems a bit cumbersome but is all I can come up with.

Comment: What happens if `Y` occur twice with: `pass, fail`?

Comment: Maybe this is off-topic, but why do 2 fails and 2 passes mean overall pass while just one fail and 2 passes mean an overall fail? Somehow that sounds really odd to me.

Comment: @QuangHoang this case will never happen, but if it did it would be `Pass`

Comment: @QuangHoang so seems like my method work then

Comment: @WeNYoBen your method still fails for 4 passes and no fails.

Comment: @MaxB is 4 pass yield pass ?

Comment: @WeNYoBen 4 pass would yield `Fail` , we are looking for equal number of `Pass/Fail` for anything that occurs more than 2 times. Also of note, data will never show up in odd numbers, so you cant have fail, pass, pass.

Comment: @MaxB check the update

Comment: Fun and confusing question hehe.

Comment: That's a really crazy logic. Do you have more of thet kind? :-)

Comment: My brain was hurting thinking of how to even ask it properly :P. I'm sure something else will come up LOL

Comment: That's what I feared :-) No, just joking

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need ? 0.5 means they are equal, 1 mean all item is pass , this two conditions yield pass

```
s=df.Judgement.eq('Pass').groupby(df['Name']).agg(['mean','count'])
((s['mean'].eq(1)&s['count'].le(2))|s['mean'].eq(0.5)).map({True:'Pass',False:'Fail'})
Out[436]: 
Name
A    Pass
F    Pass
X    Pass
Z    Fail
dtype: object
```

Comment: @WeNYoBen is right, will update question. Apologies, it should read `twice` not `once`

Comment: wouldn't `between` be a better choice here, as `isin`?

Comment: @jottbe I am not clear what he need right now , since the expected output does not match what he described

Comment: I have updated the question... If the same name occurs twice and both are pass, the judgement is pass

Comment: Maybe change `ne(4)` to `lt(3)` or `le(2)` for better generalization. Your current logic still fails for 3 passes.

Comment: first in my answer? But it's greater than 2.

Comment: But I never check `count < 2`, only `count <= 2`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196375/discussion-between-quang-hoang-and-wenyoben).

Comment: This works also for names with more than 2 results all positive.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my approach:

```
new_df = df.Judgement.eq('Pass').groupby(df['Name']).agg({'size','mean', 'max'})

is_passed = ( # check those with more than two counts
             (new_df['mean'].eq(0.5) & new_df['size'].gt(2)) 

              # those with one or two counts pass if they have a pass
             | (new_df['size'].le(2) & new_df['max'])   
            )
```

which yields:

```
Name
A     True
F     True
X     True
Z    False
dtype: bool
```

Equivalently, we can do:

```
is_passed = np.where(new_df['size'].le(2), new_df['max'] , new_df['mean'].eq(0.5))
```

and you can use `np.where` to mask `pass`, `fail`:

```
np.where(is_passed, 'pass', 'fail')
```

Comment: This also works for names with more than two tests all positive.

Comment: @jottbe Which part makes you think that it's the case?

Answer (score 1):

With custom `apply` function:

```
In [334]: def compare_pass_fail(x):
     ...:     v_counts = x['Judgement'].value_counts()
     ...:     return 'Pass' if ('Fail' not in v_counts or v_counts.get('Pass') == v_counts['Fail']) else 'Fail'
     ...: 
In [335]: df.groupby('Name').apply(compare_pass_fail)
Out[335]: 
Name
A    Pass
F    Pass
X    Pass
Z    Fail
dtype: object
```

Comment: If df contains four Passes, this returns "pass", but I think it should return "fail" according to the crazy logic.

Answer (score 1):

I used pandas groupby apply function. Logic may differ but it works for your case.

```
   df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["A","A","A","A","X","X","Z","Z","Z","F"], "Judgement" : ["Pass","Fail","Fail","Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass","Fail","Pass"]})   



  Name  Judgement
0   A   Pass
1   A   Fail
2   A   Fail
3   A   Pass
4   X   Pass
5   X   Pass
6   Z   Pass
7   Z   Pass
8   Z   Fail
9   F   Pass

def func(x):
    np = len(x[x["Judgement"] == "Pass"])
    nf = len(x[x["Judgement"] == "Fail"])
    if(np*nf == 0):
        return x["Judgement"].unique()[0]
    else:
        if(np!=nf):
            return "Fail"
        else:
            return "Pass"
df.groupby("Name").apply(func)

Name
A    Pass
F    Pass
X    Pass
Z    Fail
dtype: object
```

Comment: This returns `Pass` from names with 4 passes but no fail.

Comment: I checked it again and there is no mistake. It returns "Fail" for Z again. Check it out again you must be wrong at some point. @jottbe

Comment: Look at the result of `df= pd.DataFrame({'Name': list('VVVV'), 'Judgement': [True] * 4})`. this should be fail, because of the rule "An item that occurs more than twice can only be judged as 'Overall Pass' if (# of pass == # of fail).". I got this wrong at first as well. Really odd logic. But I think that's not important :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also generate a `DataFrame` first with the pass-fail counts and work on that:

```
df_count= df.groupby(['Name', 'Judgement']).apply(len).unstack(-1).fillna(0)
```

And then work on it's columns:

```
((df_count['Fail'] == df_count['Pass']) | ((df_count['Fail'] == 0) & (df_count['Pass'].le(2)))).map({True: 'Pass', False: 'Fail'})
```

The overall result is:

```
Name
A    Pass
F    Pass
X    Pass
Z    Fail
dtype: object
```

df_count can be used to check the result and looks like this:

```
Judgement  Fail  Pass
Name                 
A           2.0   2.0
F           0.0   1.0
X           0.0   2.0
Z           1.0   2.0
```